# How can I enable cURL for an installed Ubuntu LAMP stack?

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, lamp

I have installed the Ubuntu LAMP stack. But cURL is not enabled, and neither can I can find the extension listed in the INI file. I added it manually, but it didn't work either.

How should I enable cURL then?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Though you should address this question to serverfault

Comment: The above didn't worked out too

Comment: Answer found here too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5

Answer (score 432, accepted):

From *[Install Curl Extension for PHP in Ubuntu](http://buzznol.blogspot.com/2008/12/install-curl-extension-for-php-in.html)*:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

After installing libcurl, you should restart the web server with one of the following commands,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

*or*

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @Arsheep "didn't worked" is exceedingly unhelpful. Did it give you an error? Did your computer explode? Did your house burst into flames?

Comment: No errors and no flames man , it installed successfully i restarted Apache and retried the curl code But the same error again " Call to undefined function curl_init() "

Comment: @leonbloy -  okay i saw phpinfo() too only one "curl" word i can found in "Additional .ini files parsed  - curl.ini". Does that mean something  ?

Comment: same was happen with me , i have installed php-curl again

Comment: sudo apt-get update  -y  && sudo apt-get install -y php5-curl

Comment: You only need to install php5-curl... The rest aren't required to enable curl in PHP. I also didn't have to restart Apache for the change to take effect.

Comment: @Xethron restart is done automatically by the installation routine of apt/aptitude

Comment: This answer is old, for example ubunto 14.10 now changes the libcurl3 dependencies to libcur4.  Here's what I used successfully (it also pulled in a few more dependencies as this was a first-time install for me):
`sudo apt-get install curl libcurl4-openssl-dev php5-curl php5-cli`

Comment: After `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`, I had to create a symbolic link in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` : `ln -s ../../mods-available/curl.ini 20-curl.ini`

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 the command is now `sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Comment: On PHP 7, use `sudo apt-get install php-curl` instead of `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`.

Answer (score 124):

You only have to install the php5-curl library. You can do this by running

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

[Click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5) for more information.

Comment: @EdC In my opinion this is a better answer than the accepted, because it's enough to install php5-curl, no need for the others.

Comment: This is the better answer... simpler and there is no need to restart the webserver because apt-get does it for you

Comment: Additionally, you'd need to restart Apache after this command using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @mblackwell8 I just tried, and you MUST restart the web server after using the command in order for it to work.

Comment: Correct, an apache restart is required... FYI you could also enter:

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart (instead of 'sudo service apache2 restart) ... though this alternative method I mention requires that your directory is unchanged as it specifies a static path. I use the one mentioned by Yazin

Answer (score 29):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

It worked on a fresh [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) LTS, with *lamp-server* and *php7*. I tried with `php7-curl` - it didn't work and also didn't work with `php5-curl`.

Comment: This work perfectly fine with me. I'm using PHP7 but I used the command without the version number and it worked super fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

For those who are trying to install php-curl on PHP 7, it will result in an error. Actually if you are installing php-curl in PHP 7, the package name should be;

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Not `php5-curl` or `php7-curl`, just `php-curl`.

Answer (score 15):

First thing to do: Check for the PHP version your machine is running.

Command Line: `php -version`

This will show something like this (in my case):

> PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
> Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group

If you are using PHP 5.x.x => run command: `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

If PHP 7.x.x => run command (in my case): `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`

Enable this extension by running:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

And in the file "php.ini" search for keyword "curl" to find this line *below* and change it from

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

To:

> extension=php_curl.dll

Next, save your file "php.ini".

Finally, in your command line, restart your server by running: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 10):

I tried most of the previous answers, but it didn’t work for my machine, [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), but what worked for me was this.

First: check your PHP version

```
$ php -version
```

Second: add your PHP version to the command. Mine was:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl
```

Lastly, restart the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Although most persons claimed that it not necessary to restart Apache :)

Comment: Not need to specify the php version, just use: `sudo apt-get install php-curl` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 4):

Fire the below command. It gives a list of modules.

```
 sudo apt-cache search php5-
```

Then fire the below command with the module name to be installed:

```
 sudo apt-get install name of the module
```

For reference, see *[How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu)*.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to give version numbers. Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

It worked for me. Don't forgot to **restart** the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y curl
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for does of you who are using PHP 8.x above and Centos OS 7 you can install the php extension by running this command `yum search php81- or php80` then search for `ea-php81-php-curl.x86_64 or ea-php80-php-curl.x86_64`

After that run: `yum install ea-php81-php-curl.x86_64` to install the extension. This will also restarted the apache server along side the installation.

Hope this help solve your problem!