# how to use online CSV file data as value without downloading the file

Tags: c#, php

Hi I have a link that is download a CSV file, I would like to use the data inside to build my website, but I don't wont to download the file, is there anyway to do it?
the link is: http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fopen() or PHP cURL library:

fopen() (Usually this is not as safe as cURL, and you might run into issues when fopen is not allowed in the PHP settings file, but it is a quick and dirty way to do it):

```
// Load file into resource from URL.
$fileHandle = fopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download", "r");
// Edit: Load file resource into string.
$fileContents = fread($fileHandle);
echo $fileContents;
```

cURL (The preferred way. Read up on cURL here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$curl = curl_init(); // Open a cURL library resource.

// Set the resource option for the URL.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download");
// Set the resource option to let it return a value from the execution function.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$file = curl_exec($curl); // Execute cURL, load the result into variable $file.
curl_close($curl); // Close the cURL resource.

print_r($file); // The file should now be a string, exactly the CSV string that was scraped.
```

Comment: I have try the fopen, with echo, but I get "Resource id #3" only. Is there anything i have missed?

Comment: @PriscillaIp Sorry for the confusion. Function `fopen()` returns a file resource, which you must manipulate in order to get the string. Use `fread()` as in my edited answer and echo that return value, not the resource. If you can, I would highly recommend installing cURL as you have more control over security, etc.

Comment: Thanks Stegrex, for the fread(file,length). I also would like to use cURL, but the library install fail in my computer, it is painful and i already run out of time.

Comment: @PriscillaIp Reinstalling PHP with cURL can be a pain, I agree. Hopefully the fread() solution solved what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the file to get the data inside it.

Have your server delete it afterwards.

Comment: You can Open a stream to the file via `WebClient.OpenRead()` and assign the results to a Stream (see my answer). This is C#, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the contents of the file at runtime using cURL.

```
$url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

`$data` will now contain the contents of that file.

Comment: I just try it and result is "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()" is there anything I forget to add
code:
'<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
echo $data;
?>
</body>'

Comment: @PriscillaIp If you're getting an error saying that `curl_init()` is undefined it means that the PHP cURL library is not installed on your server. If you can't/don't want to install it try using Stegrex's `fopen()` solution instead.

Comment: Do you know any good instruction for installing the cURL library?

Comment: @PriscillaIp Priscilla, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack). They are instructions on how to enable cURL (if installed) and how to install cURL. Also check out the [cURL installation docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) from the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C# or PHP? My solution is in C#.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download");
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

string CSVContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

CSVContents now contains the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to read the data via a Stream rather than downloading the contents of the data to your physical disk. This is in C# (couldn't tell if you wanted PHP or C# since your tags include both)

```
string uriString = @"http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download";
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
Stream myStream = myWebClient.OpenRead(uriString);    //open a stream to the resource
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream);
Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());                    //print contents of stream

myStream.Close();
```

Comment: *"without actually downloading the file"* ... that's a bit misleading. You still have to bring the data from there to here. Just because it's not all buffered in memory at the same time doesn't mean you don't download the file to get the data it contains.

Comment: @rdlowrey thanks for the comment, I've updated the answer to be (hopefully) clearer.