# Using Laravel, Guzzle complains that the PHP cURL extension isn't installed

Tags: ubuntu, php, curl

When attempting to create a new Laravel project (with Laravel.phar, on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
laravel new myproject
```

I get the following error:

```
Crafting application...

[Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException]               
The PHP cURL extension must be installed to use Guzzle.  

new name
```

PHP's cURL (and all related packages I could find by googling this issue) **is** installed and enabled.

The first few lines of phpinfo()'s cURL section is:

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.22.0
Age 3
```

I can't quite figure out what's going wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get that phpinfo from the cli??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `PHP cURL` extension package needs to install. Run this command to install the package:

> sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl

Then run:

> laravel new myproject

Comment: sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl

Comment: @KrIsHnA This issue is only due to the php5-curl package.

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install php-curl` now :)

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl`, or whatever version you might need to be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

PHP usually has two different configuration files. One is for running embedded inside the webserver. The other one is when called on the command line.

Make sure you look into the right phpinfo. Run `php -i` on the command line to see the installed extensions of that version, and also see where the configuration file is located to change the installed extensions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack to install PHP5-Curl in Apache, for those who didn't know how to do so...

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5-curl