# GCM is not working on live server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notification using GCM. Everything is working perfect when I run necessary files to send messages to device from my local server (on my computer with `XAMPP` server). But when I upload files to my live server and when I run the files, I'm not getting push notification. I verified all the files but I'm not getting. Below is my `php` code:

### send_message.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST["regId"]) && isset($_REQUEST["message"]) && isset($_REQUEST["senderid"])) {
    $regId = $_REQUEST["regId"];
    $message = $_REQUEST["message"];
    $senderid = $_REQUEST["senderid"];


    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);

    $message = array("message" => $message, "sender_id" => $senderid);
    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
    echo $result;die;

}

?>
```

### GCM.php

```
<?php

    class GCM {

        function __construct() {

        }

        public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
            // include config
            include_once './config.php';


            // Set POST variables
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

            $fields = array(

                'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
                'data' => $message, 

            );

            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

            // Open connection
            $ch = curl_init();


            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

            // Execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);
            echo 'result';
            echo json_encode($fields);
            echo $result;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

I'm executing **send_message.php** file from my browser by providing server `url` and necesasry parameters. On local machine, I'm getting push notification, but while I executing the same file by providing live server `url`, it is not giving me any output. What can be the issue?

Comment: Anil, are you able to access from live url ? I mean when you put your code to live server are you able to access it using live url ?

Comment: yes, I have access of it...

Comment: Good, can you tell me that url  ?

Comment: @Kedarnath: I think, here problem is in GCM.php file's curl part...

Comment: Yes I think curl has some setting in XAamp to open it from live location.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48326/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-anil-bhatiya)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to access PHP page from live address you just need to enable `cURL` from your **XAMPP**

Go to your php.ini file and un-comment following line ( delete `;` will remove it from comment ),

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

After doing this you can check curl in phpinfo() like below image,

> [image]

For **LAMP**

From http://buzznol.blogspot.com/2008/12/install-curl-extension-for-php-in.html:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

After installing libcurl you should  restart the web server with one of the following commands,

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` OR `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Below is the link to install CURL on LAMP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be of the API Key you are using to send push notifications to the Android Device.

***Two kinds of API keys are available in the Google Developers Console***:

Use a **server key** ***if your application is running on a server***.

Use a **browser key** ***if your application is running on a client***, for example from JavaScript or any other client-side web-browser context.

Below is the screenshot of the Developers Console, where you would get the **browser & server API Keys.**

[image]