# curl extension not showing in php.ini even after installation of curl in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

i am using `php 5.5.9. ubuntu 14.04 os` .
 try to run the  `php`  function

> curl_init()

it shows an error  Call to "undefined function curl_init()" then 
1.i installed curl ([How to enable curl, installed Ubuntu LAMP stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack))
2. i checked " `php.ini`  to remove comment extension but i not found the text in  `php.ini` .

still i have the error i restarted  `apache`  many times. please help.

Comment: can you show us your complete php code? 
Post your code on your question.

Comment: make sure that the `php.ini` file you are trying to open is from `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` there are other `php.ini` for different configurations

Comment: yes,exactly i opened the same for apahe:php.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what your problem really is..

Try this, I'm sure this WORKS.

**To purge all curl and apache2 packages**

```
sudo apt-get purge curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl apache2
```

**To Install curl and apache2**

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl apache2
```

**Restart apache2**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After restarting your web-server, go to `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
search for `;extension=php_curl.dll` and remove the `;` (uncomment) and save the file, restart apache2 `sudo service apache2 restart` again.

Everything should WORK fine now.

Comment: in php.ini there is no ";extension=php_curl.dll" to uncomment. after installation. i mentioned it in question.

Comment: Did you purge the packages and install it back again?