# Amazon Web Services WP Plugin cURL Error

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, curl, openssl

Hi there I am having trouble activating a wordpress plugin "https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-web-services/"

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
>
> The official Amazon Web Services SDK requires PHP 5.3.3+ and cURL 7.16.2+ compiled with OpenSSL and zlib. Your server currently has no PHP cURL library activated.

I am on Ubuntu LAMP stack, I have checked that cURL is installed -

`php -v` outputs:

```
PHP 7.0.19-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) (built: May 22 2017 13:29:59) (NTS)
```

Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group`

`curl -V` outputs:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP`

I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: [Best Stack Exchange site for asking about Amazon AWS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141942/173448).

Comment: Found the answer: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939820/how-to-enable-curl-installed-ubuntu-lamp-stack

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Install cURL:

   `sudo apt-get install php-curl`
   OR
   `sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`
2. Enable cURL extension in `php.ini` file. `;extension=php_curl.dll` Uncomment this.

All done, Cheers!

Comment: Tired this but still facing the issue. :/

On ubuntu server curl is installed successfully but on Wordpress its missing.
`php-curl is already the newest version (2:8.2+93+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+2).`